# Hover effect for a Control that resides if a ContextMenu is opened

Tags: wpf

I want to add a hover effect for a WPF-Control.

For this, I created a Style-Trigger that changes the `Background`-Brush of the control if `IsMouseOver` is true. This works fine, however if I open a `ContextMenu` from the control, `IsMouseOver` becomes false and the hover effect stops until the `ContextMenu` is closed.

I also tried a combination of `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`, but with this, there is the same behaviour. If the context menu` is opened, MouseLeave will be fired.

I understand why I can not do it like this, but I don't see a nice way to solve my requirement. Has anyone did already something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue can be resolved by the creation of a second trigger, that checks if the attached ContextMenu is opened:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Hover_Brush}"/>                                            
</Trigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContextMenu.IsOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Hover_Brush}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

**Caveat**
The above XAML works fine, but has one issue: If the style is used for more than one item and the controls `ContextMenu` is shared, the hover effect will be activated on all items if the context menu is opened for a control.
Therefore, the context menu must not be shared. If it is defined in a resource, use the x:Shared="false" property to disable sharing. If it is directly defined under the control, this problem does not occur.